# html button doesn't show up in browser after ajax request success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm making an ajax request to an API and on success I'm adding a couple of buttons to two different div elements. It works fine locally but not on my domain.

The buttons are supposed to appear after the ajax request. I can see in the source that the button elements are there. A <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for strings "Load More" and "Excel Export" on the page shows results found, but they are not visible.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var clientId = "client";
    var key = "api-key";
    var headers = "<table id='orders' class='table'><tr><th>..</th><th>..</th><th>..</th>......</tr></table>";
    $('#response').html(headers);
    function getOrders(token) {
        var apiURL = "https://apiURL";
        if (token != "")   apiURL += "&token=" + token;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            crossDomain: "true",
            url: apiURL,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(clientId + ':' + key)))
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var data_resp = JSON.stringify(data);
                token = data.token;
                console.log(token);
                var i;
                var str = "";
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    str += "<tr><td>" + data.field1 + "</td><td>" + data.field2 + "</td><td>" +
                ......
                    +"</tr>";
                }
                $('#orders tr:last').after(str);
                $('#btndiv').html("<button id='loadButton' type='button' align='center' class='btn btn-primary'>Load More</button>");
                $("#loadButton").click(function () {
                    if (token == null) alert("API returning null token");
                    else                  getOrders(token);
                });
                var exportButtonStr = "<button id='xmlDownload' class='btn btn-success'>Excel Export</button>"
                $('#export').html(exportButtonStr);
                $('#xmlDownload').click(function () {
                    $("#orders").table2excel({
                        exclude: ".noExl",
                        name: "Orders"
                    });
                });
            },
            error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#response').text('GET tasks failed.');
            }
        });
    }

    getOrders("");
});
```

---

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>List of Orders</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.table2excel.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<b id="welcome">Welcome : <i><?php echo $login_session; ?></i></b>
<br><br>

<div id="response"></div>
<br><br>

<div id="btndiv" align='center'></div>
<br/>

<div id="export" align='center'></div>
<b id="logout">
    <a href="profile.php">Back</a>
</b>
<br>
<b id="logout">
    <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
</b>
<b id="save">Save></b>
<script src="orders.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the CSS properties for those elements with your dev tools (accessible via F12 button) in your browser.

Comment: Along the same lines, you should also check the 'Network' and (JavaScript) 'Console' tabs to see if the Ajax request is actually being generated and whether there are any unhandled errors.

Comment: @Mouser: Did that. Didn't find any bug there.

Comment: Yes, the ajax requests are being generated. I'm getting 200. Also, the table is getting rendered properly with the response.

Comment: Still is it appended to a non visible parent element. An not updated CSS file that is causing problems?

Comment: Thanks @Mouser, looking more closely at the CSS files, I found that I had an old CSS property that was messing with the <div id='response'> element. It was something like this: #response{
 position:relative;
 right:0%;
 top:0%;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 color:#000000;
 background-color: #FFFFF9;
 overflow:scroll;
}